# Paypal Rest API - Token life time from approval URL

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk, token

I use Paypal Rest API and my question is:

How long is **token** from approval URL valid? I want to store this token (also with my token) to the database and generate link with my token. Later if I click to this link (replace my token with paypal token) I want to redirect to paypal.

If i tried some old token, paypal site get error with "This transaction has expired" and "Your session has ended".

Example of approval URL:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-2W069482J43318257
```

Thank you. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They say it expires after 3 hours, and you can extend it to 72 by contacting customer service. Used it, but never contacted them, so...

Docs:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/