# Paypal Subscriptions: Approval Lifetime?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

When [a PayPal subscription is created](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create), an approval URL is made available in the response.

It looks like this, including a token:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions?ba_token=BA-012456AB393ABC890
```

The documentation does not seem to specify the lifetime of the approval link. Is there a lifetime, or is it eternal?

With previous versions of the PayPal API, similar links [have been thought to last for three hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46400527/paypal-rest-api-token-life-time-from-approval-url). In Sandbox, the link seems to last longer than 3 hours, although this might be unique to Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

Paypal's Merchant Technical Support says that "Unapproved tokens can be approved as late as 72 hours later". This is undocumented, so it could change in the future.

On the other side, remember that you can retrieve the current approval token by the HATEOAS links when you retrieve a subscription through the API.

Comment: hey @AfrOn012, are there any documentation for lifetime interval unit on paypal? I can't seem to find it or is it still not supported as of now?

Comment: I haven't seen the Paypal docs in a long time. I switched to Stripe because it has a much better dev experience. Some Paypal details aren't documented, so your best option is contacting Paypal's Merchant Technical Support and ask them directly.

Comment: Thanks. I already did. Yes PayPal is really a headache.